# Google plus signin does not return id_token

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-authentication

```
var login =  function () {
        var deferred  = $q.defer();
        gapi.auth.authorize({
          client_id: $googleplus.config('clientId'),
          scope: $googleplus.config('scopes'),
          immediate: false
        },function(response){
          console.log(response.id_token)/*Not defined */
          deferred.resolve(response);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
      }
```

Am using the above code to authenticate my users but for some reasons I don't get id_token from the request. I need this token for integration with amazon cognito 
Here is my scopes that am using
scopes : 'openid email profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer to my problem by including this parameter . 
response_type: 'token id_token'

```js
var login =  function () {
    var deferred  = $q.defer();
    gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: $googleplus.config('clientId'),
      scope: $googleplus.config('scopes'),
      response_type: 'token id_token',
      immediate: false
    },function(response){
      deferred.resolve(response);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  }
```